# Ruby on Windows send email using SMTP library

Tags: ruby, smtp, ruby-2.0

I have the following code that works perfectly on a Mac but fails on windows.

```
require 'net/smtp'

  opts = {}
  opts[:server]      ||= 'mycompany.com'
  opts[:from]        ||= 'user0@mycompany.com'
  opts[:from_alias]  ||= 'Example'
  opts[:subject]     ||= "You need to see this"
  opts[:body]        ||= "Important stuff!"

  msg = <<END_OF_MESSAGE
From: #{opts[:from_alias]} <#{opts[:from]}>
To: <user0@mycompany.com>
Subject: #{opts[:subject]}

#{opts[:body]}
END_OF_MESSAGE

  Net::SMTP.start(opts[:server]) do |smtp|
    smtp.send_message msg, opts[:from], "user0@mycompany.com"
  end
```

With the following error message...

```
Z:\util>ruby test.rb
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:540:in `initialize': Permission denied - c
onnect(2) (Errno::EACCES)
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:540:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:540:in `tcp_socket'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:550:in `block in do_start'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:66:in `timeout'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:549:in `do_start'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:519:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:456:in `start'
        from test.rb:19:in `<main>'
```

Is there something missing that i need on the windows environment to send the email?

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have permission to connect to that server without authentication. These days, any sane SMTP server is going to have some sort of authentication in place, or be totally secured. You'll need to research what sort of authorization is needed. I'd recommend talking to your server administrator.

Comment: Ok. It does not explain why it works on the Mac though

Comment: Macs have a built-in SMTP client library because they're *nix. Windows don't because they're Microsoft. Net::SMTP takes advantage of that. That's probably a starting point.

Comment: The net/smtp libraries only work on Linux, or OS's with a mail client installed similar to Postfix or Sendmail. I'm sure there is one for Outlook, or you could use Gmail.